# open a tab pane with enter key in bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, tabpanel

Once click tab key at the active tab pane's last text box, I can see next tab pane tab pane's tab header getting highlight , then once I click `EnterKey` I cannot open that tab pane,

whats wrong here , how to open tab pane with enter key in bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Check if the focus is on the next tab pane, and also see if the event `EnterKey` has something to do with the focus next tab before it executes the codes.